# What is the maximum number of grafana folders and dashboards?

Tags: grafana

An application is composed of multiple services.

I will create a folder for each application and a dashboard for each service in the application. Therefore, I need to know the maximum number of folders and dashboards in Grafana.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You may have enabled usage quotas in the Grafana config. Then those limits will be applied. Usage quotas are disabled by default, so then used database is your limit (in theory). E.g. MySQL InnoDB table may have ~64TB data, so that can be ~1G records (if one row needs 64kB, that again depends on the dashboard size) for `dashboard` table (table, where dashboards/folders are "stored").

So answer is: a lot, but it depends.

However you need to consider also user experience. You very likely notice poor experience, when some DB expensive actions will be executed - e.g. search dashboard/folder by search string. I see that with ~2k dashboards. It needs a few seconds to complete.